# How to destroy a scheduled thread as tomcat shuts down?

Tags: java, tomcat, scheduled-tasks

I have created a scheduled code call using ScheduleThreadPoolExecutor as so:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);      
stpe.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Updatey(), 0, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Which runs a simple class:

```
class Update implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //update code here
}
```

I have a ServletContextListener which calls a method when the tomcat is shutdown and does a few other tidying jobs. But I don't know how to use java to clean this extra thread up on close down. The Listener runs in separate program so it has me a bit stuck.

Does anyone know how to clean this up on close down?

TIA

Comment: Can you inject your `ServletContextListener` instance with a reference to your `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`? If so, you can then just call `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
```

Use a constructor with thread factory

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, threadFactory);
```

Your thread factory should be producing threads which are daemons so on shutdown these threads would die automatically. You could use your own factory or simply use guava's [ThreadFactoryBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html).